# Is it possible to combine variadic args with flag package usage?

Tags: go

I want my function to take optional arguments in an efficent way.

Reading similar posts led me to variadic args and I'm trying to implement it alongside the flag package (simply looking for any alternative to the users being able to run available command line flags of their choice..
This is my flag package usage:

```
func main() {
    var target string
    var method string
    flag.StringVar(&target, "target", "http://google.com/robots.txt", "Target address")
    flag.StringVar(&method, "method", "GET", "Method")
    flag.Parse()

    requests.MakeRequest(target, method)
}
```

This is an example of variadic args function:

```
func foo(params ...int) {
    fmt.Println(len(params))
}

func main() {
    foo()
    foo(1)
    foo(1, 2, 3)
}
```

Can I combine the two?
If this is not possible - how can I pass main program's user given arguments to a variadic function then?

Comment: Collect your flag args into a slice, e.g. `params := []interface{}{target, method}` or use `[]string` if they're all `string`s, and then call `foo(params...)`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to combine. Variadic functions are pretty straight forward: They work as the last argument to a function, and must be of the same type.

Comment: Combine them in what way? What are you actually trying to do here? Without any idea what you're trying to achieve the answer is basically "yes, by using them both to do whatever it is you're trying to do".

Comment: As in - I want to take the flag arguments and pass only the ones provided by the user to a different function.

Comment: @mkopriva - in your example, what if the user isn't providing , lets say, the target parameter? the default will be sent instead

Comment: If your goal is optional positional arguments, a better approach is to accept a struct as your function's argument, and allow unset fields.

Comment: then use the default value, or don't use anything, it's up to you, say you don't want to pass in target if it's empty in such a case you can conditionally append or not append the desired arg. This way, however, `foo` won't know whether the single arg that's passed in is target or method and if that's an issue for you you need to rethink your desing. E.g. passing in a single struct whose fields are all the possible args.

Comment: What would unset fields change if default flag parameters will be sent anyway?

Comment: The question is formulated understandable and after the rules. Even if the author does obviously not understand what variadic arguments are for, he provides proper sample code. I don't think the downvotes are justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question shows a misunderstanding, what variadic arguments are for.

As you realized, variadics are used, when the amount of arguments to a function varies. You try to use this concept to hand over parsed commandline arguments of a variable amount. This is a bad idea in many ways. The obvious here is, that you are coupling your commandline arguments with the distribution of the flags and arguments in your code. Another is, that the variadic arguments loose the positional information. How do you expect to identify which 4 of the 5 arguments you have received?

You should define a struct to hold the flags for your code and write a commandline parser, that fills or creates this struct from defaults and given commandline options. 
This struct is then used to provide the flags and options throughout your application.

In practice, this could look like this:

```
type options struct {
    target string
    method string
}


func main() {
    config := parseCommandLine()
    theRealStuffHappensHere(config)
}

func theRealStuffHappensHere(config options) {
    if config.method == "GET" {
    // ...
    }
}

func parseCommandLine() options {
    var config options
    flag.StringVar(&(config.target), "target", "http://google.com/robotstxt", "Target address")
    flag.StringVar(&(config.method), "method", "GET", "Method")
    flag.Parse()

    return config
}
```

The variadic arguments are heavily used in the `fmt` package, where the amount of required arguments depends on the amount of placeholders in the format string. Your usecase does not match.

Comment: Thanks man, this helps me alot. edit for future viewers: you have a missing closing bracelet for theRealStuff func, and parseCommandline with a small l in your main.

Comment: No problem. I have corrected the code in the sample.